# Вызов из объекта Json

Tags: php, json

Приветствую. Столкнулся со трудностью при использовании Json, а именно - я не знаю как обратится к декодированному объекту:

```
$array = '{"SimpleName":{"redirect_urls":["Simplelink-1","Simplelink-2","Simplelink-3"],"redirect_status":true}}';
$decode_array = json_decode($array);
```

SimpleName - может меняться. И не совсем понятно, как вызвать из него redirect_status. Попытался во так так, не работает:

```
echo $decode_array[0]->redirect_status;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = '{"SimpleName":{"redirect_urls":["Simplelink-1","Simplelink-2","Simplelink-3"],"redirect_status":true}}';
$decode_array = json_decode($array);
var_dump($decode_array);
//получаем объект
// object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
//   ["SimpleName"]=>
//   object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
//     ["redirect_urls"]=>
//     array(3) {
//       [0]=>
//       string(12) "Simplelink-1"
//       [1]=>
//       string(12) "Simplelink-2"
//       [2]=>
//       string(12) "Simplelink-3"
//     }
//     ["redirect_status"]=>
//     bool(true)
//   }

// var_dump($decode_array->SimpleName);

//получаем массив    
$decode_array = json_decode($array, true);
var_dump($decode_array);

// array(1) {
//   ["SimpleName"]=>
//   array(2) {
//     ["redirect_urls"]=>
//     array(3) {
//       [0]=>
//       string(12) "Simplelink-1"
//       [1]=>
//       string(12) "Simplelink-2"
//       [2]=>
//       string(12) "Simplelink-3"
//     }
//     ["redirect_status"]=>
//     bool(true)
//   }
// }
var_dump($decode_array['SimpleName']);
```

если ключ/свойство (переменная объекта) SimpleName может меняться,
вам нужно обходить объект/массив с использованием `foreach`

например:

```
foreach ($decode_array as $k=>$v){
    var_dump($k); //выдаст string(10) "SimpleName"
    var_dump($decode_array->$k); //выведет свойство объекта по значению переменной, т.е. $decode_array->SimpleName;
}
```

так вы сможете отловить корневой элемент, если только он у вас меняется.

если вы в принципе не знаете полей объекта, то вам и делать с ним нечего,  но, если вы хотите словить какие-то определенные поля, то вам нужен рекурсивный обход всего объекта/массива и проверка ключа. Не могу, правда, представить себе такую дикую ситуацию.

Comment: Вы обращаетесь напрямую к объекту, по его имени SimpleName. Но если не знать имени объекта, то как быть?

Comment: обновлено, между прочим.